# Why is MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START not called after reset?

Tags: android, listener, android-mediaplayer

MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START is called the very first time but not after the player is reset using .reset().

Is there another way to know when the first frame is displayed?

Thanks,

Hugo

Comment: Are you targeting and building for API 17 (4.2/4.2.2?)

Comment: Yes i'm using 4.4.2. It's called the first time around but not after I called reset and restarted another video.

Comment: You may need to provide some code - perhaps an error is occurring?